# Derivative of $H(c)=\mathbb E[(c-X)\chi_{X\leq c}]$

Tags: derivatives, expected-value, weak-derivatives

Let $c$ be a real consant, $X$ a real random variable and $H(c)=\mathbb E[(c-X)\chi_{X\leq c}]$. Show that $$H'(c)=P[X\leq c].$$ I already proved this if $X$ has a density function. But what if $X$ has no density? I thought about the weak derivative and started with $$\int \mathbb E[(c-X)\chi_{X\leq c}] \phi'(c)dc$$ for all test functions $\phi$. How can I go on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $c$. Consider the case $h > 0$, and compute
$$
    \dfrac{H(c + h) - H(c)}{h} = \dfrac{1}{h}\mathbb{E}[(c + h - X)\chi_{\{X \le c + h\}} - (c - X)\chi_{\{X \le c\}}]
$$
In case $h > 0$, we have
$$
     \dfrac{(c + h - X)\chi_{\{X \le c + h\}} - (c - X)\chi_{\{X \le c\}}}{h} = \begin{cases} 1, \text{ if } X \le c, \\\\ 1 + \dfrac{c - X}{h}, \text{ if } c < X \le c + h,\\\\ 0, \text{ if } X > c + h \end{cases}
$$
Thus,
$$
   \dfrac{H(c + h) - H(c)}{h} = \mathbb{P}(X \le c) + \mathbb{E}\left[\left(1 + \dfrac{c - X}{h}\right)\chi_{\{c < X \le c + h\}}\right]
$$
Notice that
$$
     0 \le \left(1 + \dfrac{c - X}{h}\right)\chi_{\{c < X \le c + h\}} \le 1
$$
and
$$
    \left(1 + \dfrac{c - X}{h}\right)\chi_{\{c < X \le c + h\}} \xrightarrow{h \downarrow 0} 0
$$
An application of Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem implies
$$
    \lim_{h \downarrow 0} \dfrac{H(c + h) - H(c)}{h} = \mathbb{P}(X \le c)
$$
The case $h < 0$ is similar and I'll leave it to you.

Comment: Is it also possible to calculate $D'(z)=\mathbb E[\frac{d}{dc}(c-X)\chi_{X\leq c}]=\mathbb E[\frac{d}{dc} (c\chi_{X\leq c})- X\frac{d}{dc}\chi_{X\leq c}]=\mathbb E[\chi_{X\leq c}+c\delta_X(c)]-\mathbb E[X\delta_X(c)]$, where $\delta_X(c)$ is the Dirac delta? Why is this possible or why not?

Comment: @Moritz In general, we don't have the property $$ \dfrac{d}{dt} \mathbb{E}[f(X, t)]  = \mathbb{E}\left[\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} f(X, t)\right]$$ You have to justify why you can swap, in particular, apply the dominated convergence theorem

Comment: If we can swap derivative and integral, it has to be $\mathbb E[c\delta_X(c)]-\mathbb E[X\delta_X(c)]=0$. Why is this correct?